# Реально ли в оператор IN подставить столбец?

Tags: php, mysql

В таблице имеется столбец из случайных чисел в виде строки как в массиве **154,23,123,555,4893** и т.д. Возможно ли его подставить в оператор IN, или тут только двумя запросами нужно делать?

Делаю так:

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(B.`POINTS`)
FROM
 `rs_accounts` as A
 ,`rs_achievements` as B
WHERE
  B.`ACHIEVEMENT_ID` IN (A.`ACHIEVEMENTS`);
```

В итоге оператор IN берет только самое первое число - **154**, а остальные - нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оператор IN, так же как и любой другой (если не вдаваться в очень экзотические случаи) оперирует только с текущей строкой и может брать данные только из нее.

Но никто не мешает написать внутри IN select:

```
SELECT SUM(B.`POINTS`)
  FROM `rs_achievements` as B
 WHERE B.`ACHIEVEMENT_ID` IN (select A.`ACHIEVEMENTS` from `rs_accounts` as A);
```

Учитывая вновь открывшиеся обстоятельства по структуре исходных данных, где ID умудряются лежать *через запятую в текстовом поле (!!!)* привожу запрос который такие данные способен выбрать. Но в реальной базе, с нормальным количеством записей такой запрос будет работать *очень долго* потому как никакой индекс не сможет помочь, для выполнения запроса будут выбраны все строки одной таблицы и перемножены на все строки второй, после чего отработают строковые функции и наконец like. Т.е. если в одной таблице 1000 записей и в другой 1000 - то результирующий набор перед применением like будет уже 1000000. А в нормальных базах, где записей явно больше такой запрос может работать часами. Привожу запрос, что бы показать, что в принципе на SQL можно изобразить все, главное немного воображения:

```
select * from rs_achievements A,rs_accounts B
 where concat(',',B.achievements,',') like concat('%,',achievement_id,',%')
```

И учитесь проектировать базы, согласно правилам [Нормальной формы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Comment: Что то ничего не изменилось, эффект такой же, выводит просто 154.

Comment: Но ты же берешь SUM - это сумма по всем строкам из таблицы B, с ID присутствующими в таблице A. Внимательно проверяй исходные данные в таблицах

Comment: С исходными данными всё ок, возможно плохо объяснил, вот скриншоты: [ссылка](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_10kb.1447866265.jpg) и [ссылка](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_31kb.1447866628.jpg)

Comment: Если же **IN (select A.`ACHIEVEMENTS` from `rs_accounts` as A);** заменить на **IN (123,555);** то всё ок, выводит 15, а так нет =(

Comment: А в таблице rs_accounts точно есть записи с ACHIEVEMENTS=15 ? и типы данных совпадают, там случайно не строковые значения ? Надо дать просто запросы select * из обоих таблиц и посмотреть какие значния там есть. можешь сделать дамп базы и выложить куда нибудь, тогда смогу посмотреть и сказать в чем причина. Что бы получить ответ на вопрос надо дать полные данные, думаешь в правилах stackoverflow это просто так указано

Comment: В таблице rs_accounts находятся только ACHIEVEMENTS_ID в строке через запятую, нам надо эту строку подставить в оператор IN. В итоге 15 должно быть из таблицы rs_achievements, на скриншотах показал же отчетливо, дамп залил сюда http://rghost.ru/6s7wTyjwR

Comment: Вот теперь я понял. мне в голову не могло придти "КАК" они там лежат. Просто в реляционных базах _так_ не делают, нужен список значений - его выносят в другую таблицу, отдельными записями. Я сейчас конечно посмотрю какие функции есть в MySQL но боюсь это невыполнимая задача. Почитай в интернете на тему "нормальная форма", ты умудрился уже 1ю нормальную форму нарушить, а вообще принято почти всегда держаться пятой

Comment: @Sergey ответ поправил, данные выберет. но структуру базы лучше пересмотреть

Comment: спасибо большое, то что нужно, понимаю что это наитупейшие хранение данных, но нужно именно так)

Comment: Обнаружил проблему, если в таблицу rs_accounts добавить текстовый столбец NAME с именами к примеру Влад, Петя то при выполнении запроса выводит только Влада и их общую сумму POINTS, а нужно вывести и Влада и Петю, и для каждого своя общая сумма POINTS должна быть... что то мне кажется что это одним запросом уже не сделаешь...

Comment: Ты представить себе не можешь _что_ можно выбрать одним запросом. Бывают запросы по 3-4 страницы один запрос, выдающие ворох даже не связанных данных, зато в одной таблице. Касательно вопроса тебе надо что то вроде select NAME,SUM(points) from .... where ... group by NAME

Comment: офигеть) Mike спасибо большое еще раз, всё получилось, всегда использовал простенькие запросы SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... и тому подобные, впервые столкнулся с этим CONCAT, GROUP и т.д. голова уже не соображает, утром на свежую голову буду вникать что и как там работает)

Comment: @Sergey Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.